# Oracle - Selecting the record with maximum (latest date)

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I'm using ORACLE 8.0. I've a cylinder master, a transaction log header file, and transaction log tail(detail). the structure is as follows:

Mcylinder : ID,CSTAGE, 
TCYLINDERHD : logno, logdate, accode, docref, mmode, 
Tcylindertl : logno, id

1. For a log header, there will be many log tails
2. For each of the Cylinders with CSTAGE as 4 in mcylinder, I want the details of the latest date of the cylinder transaction with mmode (same as CSTAGE) = 4 from the log files.

I tried several methods without success. The last sql that I tried is below:

```
    SELECT cout.ID,tlog.LOGNO,tlog.LOGDATE,tlog.ACCODE,tlog.DOCREF
FROM
(SELECT "ID" FROM "MCYLINDER" WHERE "CSTAGE"=4 ORDER BY "ID") cout,
(SELECT  "LOGNO","LOGDATE","ACCODE","DOCREF" FROM "TCYLINDERHD" WHERE "MMODE" = 4 order by "LOGNO") tlog,
(SELECT  MAX(a."LOGDATE"),b."ID",b."LOGNO" FROM "TCYLINDERHD" a,"TCYLINDERTL" b
  WHERE (a."MMODE" = 4) AND  (a."LOGNO" = b."LOGNO") GROUP BY b."ID" order by b."ID",b."LOGNO") mlog
WHERE (cout.ID=mlog.ID AND mlog.LOGNO=tlog.LOGNO)
order by cout.ID;
```

The SQL shows an error saying missing paranthesis. I don't know why. Also is this the correct way to do this?

Please help.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, remove all the parenthesis, in Oracle you don't need them.
Secondly, if I correctly understood, what you're trying to achieve, try the query below. If it doesn't help, consider adding sample data and desired result to your question, so it'll be easier to help you.

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.logno, t3.logdate, t3.accode, t3.docref FROM MCYLINDER t1 
       INNER JOIN TCYLINDERTL t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
       INNER JOIN TCYLINDERHD t3 ON t2.logno = t3.logno
WHERE t1.cstage = 4
      AND t3.mmode = 4
      AND t3.logdate >= ALL (SELECT t4.logdate FROM TCYLINDERHD t4 
                                    INNER JOIN TCYLINDERTL t5 ON t4.logno = t5.logno
                             WHERE t5.id = t2.id AND t4.mmode = t3.mmode)
```